# Angular 6 update *ngFor data with item select from drop down

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a drop down select that a user can select what data they want to look at and eventually edit.  There are a few input boxes that I can update the input data on, via the drop down select, but I have an *ngFor that builds a lot of data on the page, from a data hash.  I want to be able to call the data from the data hash based upon the drop down selection.

Here is a code example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmyqrn

I have it loading a sample input that I have defined as a constant

```
SOURCE_DESTINATION_PARAMETERS_VALUES_DATA
```

and it is point to the DATA00 hash, but I don't want it as a constant and I don't know where to assign it to automatically update the other fields.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a requirement to have your data split the way you have done so?

`export const SOURCE_DESTINATION_PARAMETERS_VALUES_DATA00: SOURCE_DESTINATION_PARAMETERS_VALUES_DATA_LAYOUT[] = [
    {`

If you are defining the data this way then you will eventually need to look it up that way. Note that if instead you had it all inside a JSON object, you could navigate the object instead.

Comment: @JuanM.Medina Thank you for your response Juan.  I am curious how I could go about making a JSON object out of it, and importing it that way.  I think eventually I would want to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry!!!

I figured out I could use an **enter code here** `switch` to assign the values with in the **onChange** to reset the `this.sourceDestinationParametersValuesData` value.  I also forgot to put in the `this.` in my first attempt to change the data object.

Oh well.  The solution is out there on:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmyqrn